# Algebra , Theory of sets

Tags: combinatorics

Hello i could really need some help on this problem :

Given a set $A$ of $2^k$ strictly positive integers prove that there exist a subset of $A$, say $B$ such that $Card(B)\geq k+1$ and no two different elements in $B$ add up to one element in $A$.

Comment: Where did you come across this question, please?

Comment: RMS 2016 oral exams

Comment: Thanks. What's RMS?

Comment: A French math magazine

Comment: A magazine has oral exams? How does that work?

Comment: it works perfectly well in France , the magazine publishes articles , oral exams and IMO stuff as well , but only a subscribed individal can have acces to the solutions , not all the solutions but some of them

Comment: We are getting nowhere, fast. Please, an oral exam for what?

Comment: ENS Oral exams , admission exams

Comment: And what might ENS be?

Comment: the most prestigious science and litterarture school in all of france

Comment: I think it stand for Ecole Normale Superiéure (or however it is written)

Comment: Order the elements of $A$ $a_1,a_2,...,a_{2^k}$. If we put $a_{2^k}$ in $B$, the worst that can happen is that $a_{2^k}=a_{2^k-n}+a_n$ for $n=1,...,2^{k-1}-1$. By taking out the elements in $a_1,...a_{2^{k-1}-1}$ that satisfy one of those equalitites we eliminate the posibility of $a^{2^k}$ being the sum of two elements, and we excluded less than half of the remaining elements of $A$. Now continue, take the largest remaining element of $A$ and put it in $B$. Remove from $A$ those elements from its lower half that might be part of a sum that results in the element just added to $B$.

Comment: After $k$ insertions in $B$ we still have at least one extra element in $A$, which we put in $B$. This is because halving $2^k$, $k$ times is $1$.

Comment: @uSir470888 I don't understand what you do. Why would $a_{2^k} = a_{2^k-n}+a_n$ be the “worst”? We can have $a_{2^k} = a_{2^k-1}+a_{2^k-2}$. There are cases where every other element (except one) appear as a solution of $a_{2^k} = a_i+a_j$, for instance $A=\{1,2,\dots,2^k\}$.

Comment: @Idéophage That is what I said. The worst case is all those pairs giving a sum. Didn't you read the "for $n=1,2,...,2^{k-1}-1$"?  Removing the smaller summand from each pair removes at most half of the elements. In order to understand you first need to read everything that is written.

Comment: @uSir470888 I had read your whole argument, I am sorry I didn't understand. Now I understand. What I did not understand was what you meant by “worst”: the maximum number of pairs summing to $a_{2^k}$.

Comment: @uSir470888 Moreover “By taking out the elements in $a_1,...a_{2^{k−1}−1}$ that satisfy one of those equalitites we eliminate the posibility of $a_{2^k}$ being the sum of two elements” confused me since the elements we take out could be in the upper half of $A$ and not only in the lower half.

Comment: @uSir470888 But now I don't understand what happens in the case (for instance) $A=\{100,51,49,30,19,3,2,1\}$. Your algorithm first selects $100$ and removes $49$ (if I understand correctly). Then, it selects $51$. Then, it selects $30$ and finally $19$. But $30+19=49$. What did I miss? (I cannot remove my +1 now…)

Comment: @Idéophage Each selection of an element for $B$ requires eliminating the smaller summands. Once $100,51,49$ got placed in $B$ one looks at the sums that give $49$: $49=30+19$ and any others if there were. Then remove the $19$. The removed terms are always less than half of the terms that remain. There remain $3,2,1$. Pick $3$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63754/discussion-between-ideophage-and-usir470888).

Comment: That is why the argument ends with explaining why $2^k$ divided by $2$, $k$ times doesn't exhaust the set. At most it reduces it to $1$, and that is the $1$ in $k+1$.

Comment: @uSir470888 Don't you want to continue in chat? $49$ cannot be placed in $B$ if there is already $51$ there. 
From what I understand, at each iteration your algorithm selects the largest number x in A, removes all the lower summands of the sums u+v=x with u and v in A (the set is at most cut in half) and continue with the new set. Is that correct? If so, that does not work…

Comment: @Idéophage Just sit on it for a while. It does work. I misspoke in the comments immediately above by including $49$. The 49 gets deleted when the $100$ and $51$ get added. The $19$ doesn't get deleted because the $49$ was not added to $B$. The resulting $B$ of the process is $B=\{100,51,30,19\}$.

Comment: @uSir470888 Ok, so we agree, that is what I said in the comment where I gave that example of $A$ ($B=\{100,51,30,19\}$). But $19+30=49∈A$, so this set does not satisfy the requirement. The requirement is that the sum of two elements of $B$ is never an element of $A$. Did you understand that it must never be an element of $B$?

Comment: Proof by induction on $k$. Write $m=2^k$. Consider integers $a_1>a_2>\cdots>a_{2m}>0$. By the induction hypothesis, we can choose $k+1$ integers from $a_1,\dots,a_m$ so no difference is $a_i$ for any $i$, $1\le i\le m$. Now there are only ${k+1\choose2}=k(k+1)/2$ such differences, and $k(k+1)/2<m$ for $k\ge1$, so we can choose another number from $a_{m+1},\dots,a_{2m}$ which isn't a difference.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I don't understand why you speak of differences since we want that no *sum* is $a_i$ for $1≤i≤m$. I also tried by induction but take for instance $\{1,2,3,4,50,51,52,54\}$. Suppose our induction hypothesis gives $\{50,51,52\}$ (and not $\{51,52,54\}$ which would work). Then we cannot complete it with neither $1$, $2$, $3$ nor $4$.

Comment: @Ide, if we don't have $a_r-a_s=a_t$, then we also don't have $a_r=a_s+a_t$. And, in your example, the induction would start with $k=0$ and pick 54. Then $k=1$, pick 52. Then $k=2$, pick 50 or 51. And with either one of those choices, you can extend to $k=3$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Ok, I understand, that is because the $i$th choice is made before $a_{2^i}$ (that was not said in the induction hypothesis). But there are more than $k(k+1)/2$ possible differences $a_r-a_s$ with $a_r∈A$, $a_s∈B$ and $a_r>a_s$. There are $2^{k-1}-1$. (This is actually the same things as I did below.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us call a subset $B⊆A$ *valid* if two elements of $B$ never give an element of $A$ when added.

A greedy algorithm is to place in $B$ at each step the greatest element $x∈A\setminus B$ such that $B∪\{x\}$ is still valid. Let us prove that this algorithm will always select at least $k+1$ elements.

When we place a new element $x$ in $B$, we mark it and we also mark the elements $y$ of $A$ such that $x+y∈A$. Remark that we cannot mark more elements than the number of elements of $A$ greater than $x$.

Let $u_m$ be the maximum number of marked elements before step $m$ (starting at $0$). Then $u_0 = 0$: we start with no element marked. Before step $m$, we have marked at most $u_m$ elements in $A$. So, if $u_m<|A|$, there is a greatest element which is not marked and we can select it. That element have at most $u_m$ elements greater than it, and so we will mark at most $u_m+1$ new elements at this step. We then have $u_{m+1} = u_m + u_m + 1$. This gives $u_m = 2^m-1$.

Since $u_k=2^k-1<2^k$, the algorithm will do at least $k+1$ steps (we start at the step number $0$).

Comment: And exactly what you missed in my comment is what this argument is missing. Why the marked elements do not manage to exhaust the whole set before the $k+1$ elements get chosen.

Comment: @uSir470888 They do not exhaust the whole set because we mark less elements than what the set contains ($u_m ≤ n$). The elements I mark are not the same as in your answer.

Comment: @uSir470888 I rewrote the explanation to make it more precise.